# NSIndexPath return nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a `UIViewController` with a table view. Table  row contains buttons which trigger an action.

```
//This is my button selector inside tableview delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath

[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPress:event:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//This is button action



 -(void)onButtonPress:(UIButton*)sender {
       CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

       DestinationViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationViewController"];
       controller.args=myArgs;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];


 }

//this is my back button action

- (IBAction)onBackPressed:(id)sender {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

At first time all is working fine but after  i navigated to other  `ViewController` and return back to tableview controller by  pressing back button and again click on table row button the  `NSIndexPath` is nil

i have tried this [indexPathForRowAtPoint returns nil only for first cell in a uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368525/indexpathforrowatpoint-returns-nil-only-for-first-cell-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending a delegate to the nextviewcontroller like

```
   DestinationViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestinationViewController"];
   controller.args=myArgs;
   controller.delegate = self;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and when traversing back from that viewController to the present table viewcontroller pass that delegate.

This may help you...

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.how can i travers back ? can you give me sample?. because all my data in that should preserve.

Comment: Can you show me the code by which you are traversing to the present viewcontroller and the code by which you are showing the next viewcontroller

Comment: `controller.delegate = self;` add this line to your code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you have Buttons within TableViewCells and you don't get the IndexPath when you tap one of the buttons.

Of course is there no IndexPath since you never tapped a cell. Basically you ignore the complete tableview mechanism.

When creating the tableviewcell, tag the buttons with the index. Not the best approach, but will do.

Comment: i said after i clicked on button which is inside my table row(myBtn)

Answer (score 0):

Set tag of button equal to indexPath.row and find the NSIndexPath from tag.

```
myBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPress:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)onButtonPress:(UIButton*)sender {

UIButton *btnSender =(UIButton *)sender;

 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btnSender.tag inSection:0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't use the method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` to get the `indexPath`. You can archive it with a different way. First add an `UIView` category:

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (TableCell)

-(UITableViewCell*)getTableCell;

@end
```

and implementation

```
@implementation UIView (TableCell)

-(UITableViewCell *)getTableCell
{
   while (self.superview) {
      if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
         return (UITableViewCell*)self.superview;
      }else {
         return [self.superview getTableCell];
      }
   }
   return nil;
}
```

Now, in your `onButtonPress:` you can do like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [sender getTableCell];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]
```

Comment: what is the different in this method

Comment: Your method is based on the view layout and it may not work if the view hasn't finished layout. This method guarantees to return an index whenever you have a cell.

Comment: i am new to iOS platform will you please explain how should i implement this.

Comment: this way now i am getting my cell UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

Comment: this way i am getting button btn=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:111];

Comment: No it is wrong. I am on mobile right now so it is hard to edit the answer. You can search how to implement category in ios and try it. I will edit the answer when I am back my computer

Comment: A quick way to do is cell = sender.superView.superView.superView.

Comment: But it is for ios 7. You should try to call superView until you found the UITableViewCell

Comment: From how you get the button from the cell, it should be sender.superView to get back the cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93598/discussion-between-sahara108-and-askarc-ali).

Answer (score 0):

My suggest you can write [tableView reload] under 'viewWillAppear';
Or use other way like block to implement

Comment: even i did it but no use